# Wake on LAN on Arch on a Macbook Air 2012

Tags: arch-linux, macintosh, wake-on-lan

I've checked that my Mac supports WOL under MacOS, but running 
`sudo ethtool wlp2s0b1`
under Arch (according to the Wiki), I see only

```
Settings for wlp2s0b1:
        Link detected: yes
```

and `sudo ethtool -s wlp2s0b1 wol g` returns

```
Cannot get current wake-on-lan settings: Operation not supported
  not setting wol
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Wake-on-LAN with ethtool doesn't seem to work for Wi-Fi. From their website:

> ethtool is the standard Linux utility for controlling network drivers and hardware, particularly for wired Ethernet devices.

From the name, `wlp2s0b1`, it seems to be a Wireless device. Check the correct device name.

If you get `Operation not supported` (using sudo or with a privileged user), the drivers might not support WOL.

Comment: It does work with Wi-Fi under MacOS (from sleep, not poweroff).